# Weird ruby segmentation fault with DBI and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, segmentation-fault, dbi

The following code gives a segmentation fault on the last line

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'dbi'
require 'dbi'
require 'mysql'

dsn = "DBI:Mysql:DATABASE:www.HOST.net" # redacted
dbh = DBI.connect(dsn, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD") # redacted

sth = dbh.execute("select  * from TABLE where numeric_value is not null limit 10;") # redacted
```

It's definitely the last line that's causing the problem -- a print statement on the next line doesn't ever get executed.

Does anyone know why such a simple attempt would fail?

I'm running this on Windows, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: I would add puts statements between the matrix calculations. I believe this has nothing to do with the matrix - just that you get the error on the last line of the script. If you manage to print mtmi, you will see that this is some resource problem with the database rather than with the matrix.

Comment: @Yuval F: yes, I tried that, and it's definitely seg-faulting on the inverse() call (specifically in rational.rb according to the error message). It's so weird. I've reordered the code in various ways, and if I put the database connection stuff after the matrix stuff, then it all works fine.

Comment: I've completely edited the question now, as I've got the seg-fault to occur without any Matrix code (you were right, Yuval!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be any number of things, from the version of DBI, Mysql gem, mysql version, and ruby version.

Unfortunately ruby isn't a first class citizen on windows, nor are all configurations tested extensively on it.

First enable debugging on your VM to reproduce this issue with more information about where and why the segfault is happening.  Pass the -d option the VM.  From there you will hopefully have more info to where to look for the solution.

I'd suggest, check your patch level of your VM

```
ruby --version
```

I'd also check the level of DBI, and Mysql

```
  # if you are using gems
  gem list --local
```

You could also switch how you are accessing Mysql, ActiveRecord uses it's own code to connect to mysql, which is more extensively tested.  May not be the best solution but should not rule it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're getting a segfault in this code.

It is possible that, for instance, if you overrun the bounds of the array, you may not actually segfault until you try to run the code or access the memory that you overwrote. So you could have a system that runs for days before it segfaults if it only wrote in memory the process owns in an area it didnt' access often.